# Freehub threading

Tags: shimano, rear-wheel, freehub

I have a set of dmd wheels the 8 speed freehub has sheared off, got the piece out and ordered a new Shimano profile M22 thread freehub, when came to fit, the thread is 22.5 mm around same but coarser than m22 at about 2.5 mm pitch.
Any idea what this is and where to get a hub?

Got it. It's a Cannondale C4  k86047 for Shimano . Took a lot of research to find it. Found one reduced luckily . Definitely not an e bay or Amazon item

Comment: Welcome to the site - thank you for sharing your findings.  Do take a moment to read the [tour] and learn how the site works.

Comment: Pictures would help. But, the main ones that are like that is Joytech.

Comment: You should post your answer as an actual answer so if someone searches and finds your question they'll see it's been answered.